Best way to patch small holes in sheet metal (for optics)
I am aware this is not the most important thing but it just bothers me. The moron of a contractor who installed my sub-panel left the main breaker out (which I meanwhile installed back myself) and cut a dirty piece of sheet metal to cover the whole (attached with self tapping screws):

What is the best way to patch these holes? It would be mainly for the looks.

Since it's a new panel, just order a new deadfront cover from an authorized dealer.   When you reinstalled the 200A breaker, did you use a torque wrench to the spec on the panel labeling?  Or just "gud-n-tite"?  Because the latter is not reliable and will arc and start a fire in the panel.  We see it all the time.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica I’ll look into it but it seems that’s well over 100$. Maybe not worth it. Yes, “gud-n-tite”. Even though I feel good tight. I know off topic but would you have a recommendation for a torque wrench that works as broadly as possible but is not the worst either? I was thinking of getting one back then but I didn’t want to get a tool I’d use only once. And I was wary of all the “promising” options off Amazon.

generally electrical is too fine for a mechanic's torque wrench to be useful.  My lowest torque on my car is 10 FOOT-pounds, I've not seen electrical torques above 100 INCH-pounds. The ranges don't overlap.  To avoid junk, don't do mail-order. Mail-order bypasses consumer protections by having the true seller be overseas in a legally untouchable country.

Easy button is a square of black electrical tape run around the 200A switch.

That’s actually easy and creative solution! I like it. Will go for that.

Could even make it some other color (red?) electrical tape for some visual variety.

I would go with some black grommets or plugs.
Another simple option would be some small setcrews and nuts.
A third, not so liked by me, would be to make sure they are flat then fill with silicone or a resin type glue with a backing.
